# Выполнение хранимой процедуры pyodbc + ms sql 2005

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго дня.
Столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера:
Есть процедура в MS SQL которая делает 4 последовательных update.
Есть приложение на python 3.4 которое вызывает хранимку, но в итоге выполняется всего один update из 4-х. В чем причина?

Строка коннекта к БД

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s" %(server, dbname, login, password))
```

Далее пытаюсь выполнить процедуру

```
excur = conn.cursor()
key = input('Для продолжения\nНажмите ENTER ')
if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 255 and len(key) == 0:
    excur.execute("exec dbo.proc_Repack @CaseFrom = ?, @CaseTo = ?, @UserName = ?", CaseFrom, CaseTo, UserName)
    conn.commit()
```

В SSMS 2005 процедура выполняется на ура.

Comment: Проблему решил. Дело было в хранимой процедуре.